# Чи стало дієлово “ґуґлити” усталеним та самостійним?

Tags: переклад, вживання-слів, значення-слів, етимологія

Вивчаючи, в черговий раз, корисну інформацію, натрапив на статтю "[Як правильно *гуглити* (інформаційна грамотність науковця у XXI ст.)](http://aphd.ua/yak-pravylno-huhlyty-informatsiina-hramotnist--naukovtsia-u-xxi-st/)".
І, в процесі ознайомлення, виникло декілька запитань: без сумніву, дане слово ("*ґуґлити*") отримало широко розповсюджене і дедалі глибше входить в наше сучасне життя, але, чи здобуло воно право бути більш-менш офіційним або використовуватись при діловій мові? А якщо вже й вживаємо це слово, то яке його вірне написання: "гуглити" чи “ґуґлити”?

У широкому вжитку, використовується обидва варіанти написання: але "[гуглити](https://www.google.com.ua/search?q=%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&hl=uk&ei=ZHAFW_nwNsalsgGKsYjgBA&start=0&sa=N&biw=1304&bih=672)" більш поширений, в т.ч. і [ЗМІ](https://www.epravda.com.ua/news/2018/03/9/634826/), ніж "[ґуґлити](https://www.google.com.ua/search?hl=uk&source=hp&ei=HmkFW4eBHYqVsgGRuYmACw&q=%D2%91%D1%83%D2%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&oq=%D2%91%D1%83%D2%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&gs_l=psy-ab.3...1469.1469.0.2755.3.2.0.0.0.0.119.119.0j1.1.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..2.0.0.0...0.5upZNMnWomM)" але він теж [використовується](http://uainfo.org/blognews/1515058004-gugliti-yak-profi-kilkanadtsyat-korisnih-pidkazok.html).

При зверненні до Вікіпедії перш за все [потрапляємо](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9A%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%BF%27%D1%8E%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9_%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B3) на "Комп'ютерний сленг":

> ґуґлити — див. гуглити
>   [Гуглити](https://uk.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%B3%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D1%96_%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D1%96_%D0%BC%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%BA%D0%B8): шукати в Google.

"Офіційний сайт Української мови" поки що не надає відповідної інформації:
ні про варіанти написання "[ґуґлити](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D2%91%D1%83%D2%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&t=0)" ні про "[гуглити](https://ukrainskamova.com/search/?q=%D0%B3%D1%83%D0%B3%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&t=0)"
На "Словотворі" досить [однозначно](https://slovotvir.org.ua/words/guglyty): тут пропонують написання саме "ґуґлити".
"Український правопис" [не допоміг](http://www.pravopys.net/#search=%D2%91%D1%83%D2%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8).
"Вікісловник" [теж](https://uk.wiktionary.org/w/index.php?search=%D2%91%D1%83%D2%91%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B8&title=%D0%A1%D0%BF%D0%B5%D1%86%D1%96%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0:%D0%9F%D0%BE%D1%88%D1%83%D0%BA&profile=default&fulltext=1&searchToken=8a33yp83qlqboa2y74ng2cy8x).
СУМ-20 [містить](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=179006&page=703) тільки "гуглю".

Отже, чи здобуло це слово право бути більш-менш офіційним або використовуватись в розмовній, при діловій мові, адже в ЗМІ - вже користуються? А якщо вже й використовуємо це слово, то яке його правильне вживання: "гуглити" чи “ґуґлити”?

Answer (score 1):

<sup>Не відповідь з 1/гугол відповіддю — закріплення чи розширення питання.</sup>

Головоног, як проти анґліцизмів, колись радив використовувати звичаєве слово [*шукати*](//drive.google.com/file/d/1mJcpvbLuVsjiEpvySqnKbKv0flhOoDvL) замість *ґуґлити*. Загалом таке слово цілком підходить, коли не потрібне уточнення як пошук лиш мережею чи тільки осідком Google — навіть тут вже маються декілька означень. Окрім згаданого запитувачем суміжного слово *ґуґля*, як старовиного одягу, існує ще, від котрого і походить назва Google, слово [*гугол*](http://services.ulif.org.ua/expl/Entry/index?wordid=199346), як число 10<sup>100</sup>. Тобто, по-моєму, в деякому сенсі це слово, хоч і в доволі рідких обставин, можна також тлумачити, як дію з цим числом, коли врахувати такі слова як [*двоїти*](http://sum.in.ua/s/dvojity), [*троїти*](http://sum.in.ua/s/trojity)… Але, справді, слово дуже вживане, навіть відомі анґлійські словники [додали](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/google) *to google* до свого переліку. Правда, українські сучасні словники [не дуже](//e2u.org.ua/s?w=google&highlight=on) встигають за часом, тому з усталеністю тут все складніше.